# Matching Generic Methods to XMLDoc Output With Reflection

Tags: c#, generics, xml-documentation

I'm basically trying to match up reflected members in my library with the XMLDoc that was outputted alongside it.

When coming across generic types, I'm having a little trouble. So, for example, take this class:

```
public class GenericClass<T, U> {
    public void DoSomething<V>(U u, V v, string s) { ... }
}
```

The XMLDoc member name for `DoSomething` will look like this:

> Namespace.GenericClass.DoSomething``1(`1, ``0, System.String)

I'm finding it generate that string though to be able to find it in the documentation XML. Basically, the XMLDoc works like this: `1 means the second generic type parameter of the class (e.g. U), and ``0 means the first generic type parameter of the method (e.g. V).

But how do I match it up like that, using reflection and `MethodInfo`/`ParameterInfo`, so I can find the correct entry in the XMLDoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did this by matching the `Type` of each `ParameterInfo` to the list of Generic type parameters I had from the method and its declaring type(s).